# Embeding PDF in Excel using VBA with OLEObjects only gives first page

Tags: excel, vba, ole-object

I'm using VBA to print multiple part numbers, but when I embed the pdf object into Excel I only get the first page of the pdf. I will need all pages of the pdf. If possible, I would like to make a new excel sheet for each page of the pdf. The only way I can think to do it is to split each pdf as the macro is printing each part number, which will be rather cumbersome. The code I am starting with is below.

Note... the pdf I am accessing is in my download folder

```
Sub pdf_embed()
'
    Range("a1").Select
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add Filename:="PDF_LOCATION", _
        Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
    
End Sub
```